# While the reading of image for RGB pixel values there is different value of green in matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, rgb, getpixel

I want to obtain the pixel values for RGB from image.I did it in Matlab and Python but i obtained different values especially at the green value.
I'll appreciate if you have an advice about this matter.
Thanks
Here is my code in python

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open("lena.jpg")
imPixelVal = np.ones(np.size(im))
imSize = np.size(im)

for i in range (0,imSize[0]):
            for j in range (0,imSize[1]):         
                ij = i , j
                p = im.getpixel(ij)
                imPixelVal[i,j] = (0.2989 * p[0]) + (0.5870 * p[1]) + (0.1140 * p[2])
                print p[0]
                print p[1] 
                print p[2]
```

Also this is the code in Matlab:

```
Im=imread('lena.jpg');
Img = (ones(size(Im,1),size(Im,2))); 

for i=1:size(Im,1)
      for j=1:size(Im,2)
          Img(i,j)=0.2989*Im(i,j,1)+0.5870*Im(i,j,2)+0.1140*Im(i,j,3);
      end
end
Im(1,1,1)
Im(1,1,2)
Im(1,1,3)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and an example of the data differences?

Comment: it might be interesting to know which data format your images are having.

Comment: Give specifics on what code you used and what the differences are.

Comment: I editted and added the code for Python and Matlab

Comment: Since JPEG is a lossy format, different readers can be off by +/-1 from each other quite easily depending on how they round the decoded values. Schorsch's answer is likely to be the correct one though.

Comment: @Mark That's interesting to know. However, I checked for this case and all values are identical between Python and Matlab

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the images are read in a different "direction" in Python compared to Matlab.
If you change your python code to:

```
ij = j , i
```

instead of

```
ij = i , j
```

you'll get the same output as in Matlab.

---

If you want Matlab to give the same results as Python, you'd have to flip `i` and `j` there:

```
Img(j,i)=0.2989*Im(j,i,1)+0.5870*Im(j,i,2)+0.1140*Im(j,i,3);
```

---

Here's how I figured this out through simple debugging:

- First, I got the image from [here](http://sipi.usc.edu/database/database.php?volume=misc&image=12#top) and saved it as `.jpg`.
- Then, I changed the Matlab loops to

  ```
  for i=1:2
      for j=1:2
  ```

  So that I would only get the first 4 pixels.
- By printing both `i`, `j` and the contents of `Im` I got:

  ```
  i = 1, j = 1
  225, 137, 125

  i = 1, j = 2
  227, 139, 127

  i = 2, j = 1
  224, 136, 124

  i = 2, j = 2
  226, 138, 126
  ```
- Now, I did the same in python:

  ```
  for i in range (0,2):
      for j in range (0,2):
  ```
- This gave me:

  ```
  (0, 0)
  225 137 125
  (0, 1)
  224 136 124
  (1, 0)
  227 139 127
  (1, 1)
  226 138 126
  ```
- This showed me that the order is different between Matlab and Python.
- Hence, changing `i` and `j` in Python from `ij = i, j` to `ij = j, i` will reproduce the Matlab results.

Comment: @lisa - please consider accepting this answer, or leave a comment if it didn't work for you